# Database integrity validation with signature

Tags: c#, database, hash, data-integrity

My requirement is to ensure every row of a table was not modified manually (with SSMS, ...).

The idea was to add a "signature" column, which contains a HASH of the row data, and including an additional value provided from the APP. Then we cannot reproduce the HASH from SSMS or any other tool. The APP will be the only client of this database.

Does it sounds like a good idea ? How to enforce row integrity ? Is there an easier or more secure way?

Thanks for your help

Comment: "Is there an easier or more secure way" : What is your use case? Securing against unauthorized attackers or securing against change from people to whom you actually gave access to the database?

Comment: Just give the app the only SQL server login that has write permissions. Your way is basically just storing a password in the app anyway.

Comment: securing against change from people. There is a lot of DBA. We want to avoid if one forget to lock is computer, someone can "accidentally" change data from SSMS without wqe know it. We don't have to prevent change, just a way to identify row was changed

Comment: What if someone leaves their computer unlocked and someone "accidentally" changes data **via the app**?

Comment: That is not the requirement. Want to protect from DB side changes. However if you have a double validation mechanism, where DB and APP are closely coupled and cannot work without another, I take it also

Comment: Why doesn't using SQL login permissions solve this problem? If the only changes should come via the app, just give the app write permission and noone else. If DBAs actually need write permissions, then how could you determine that their legitimate changes were legitimate?

Comment: If you start removing permissions to SA account, soon or later the DBs will be a nightmare to manage, that is why this is not the wished solution.

Comment: And we really don't want correction from the DB. The APP allows to make correction if needed

Comment: Well, you could use SQL Server Auditing or change tracking, but if you don't trust the admin account (someone could *accidentally* disable auditing), then I guess you are left with the cryptographic approach. I hope you consider performance and maintenance though - you'll have to validate the hashes all the time, and you'll have to select every column that's included in the hash, not just specific columns.

Comment: And of course, there's still the problem of a dev leaving their machine unlocked and someone "accidentally" copying the secret key..